# Cutting down runtime of csv parser

Tags: java, csv, parsing, gwt, runtime

I have a dataset of 230'000 entries in a csv file. 1 line looks like this:

```
1849-06-01,24.844,1.402,Abidjan,CÃ´te D'Ivoire,5.63N,3.23W
```

now when I tried splitting the entries into an array, then creating an object and adding latter object to an arraylist, I failed. I later noticed that it has to do with the number of entries I try it with. I found 20'000 to be the absolute maximum. My parser looks like this:

```
try {
        new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "test20.csv").sendRequest("", new RequestCallback() {

            String data[] = new String[20000];
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request req, Response resp) {
                String text = resp.getText();
                data = text.split("\n");
                for(String str: data) {

                    String[] results = new String[6];
                    results = str.split(",");

                    // creates DataTableObject using the constructor
                    DataTableObject object = new DataTableObject(results[0], results[1], results[2], results[3], results[4], results[5], results[6]);
                    dataSet.add(object);
                }
                drawTable(dataSet);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request res, Throwable throwable) {
                // handle errors
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the `drawTable()` method just inserts all the created objects into a flextable.

dataSet is an `ArrayList<DataTableObject>`, those objects just contain all the `Strings` (city, country, etc.)

the whole thing runs with GWT `2.7.0` and `JDK 1.8`.

Do you have any idea on how to be able to draw all the 230'000 entries without hitting a timeout in the browser?

I've tried working without objects, but that doesn't cut down the runtime notably. Neither does only splitting by `\n` or `,`.

Thanks

Comment: Not your question, but delete `String data[] = new String[20000];` and change to `String [] data = text.split("\n");`

Comment: Do you want to add 230,000 lines to add GUI table?

Comment: @Scary Wombat. Very true, will do. Thanks! And yes, unfortunately I need a complete, unfiltered view of all the 230k...

Comment: A web browser may not be for you then - even a plain HTML file with 230,000 rows of already generated content will be very slow in any browser, and running code in js (or gwt/java, same thing) to generate that much HTML will take a considerable amount of time as well. There are other ways to _fake_ having that much data without actually rendering them though, including a "find" tool, but with that much data any solution is going to be slow in JS.